# How can I preserve the size of patch collections

Tags: python, matplotlib

For a very simple demonstration, I wrote the code below.

```py
from math import radians
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection

patch = mpatches.RegularPolygon(
        (0, 0),
        numVertices=6,
        orientation=radians(90),
        radius=6
    
    )

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(10,10))
fig.dpi
for i in range(6):
    # For my actual application, I had more than one patch in the PatchCollection
    pc = PatchCollection([patch])
    # I wanted to spam the same `PatchCollection` on a figure
    pc.set_offsets((i*20,i*20))
    ax.add_collection(pc)


ax.set_aspect("equal")
ax.set_xlim((-10,300))
ax.set_ylim((-10,300))
plt.show()
```

This produced a plot like this:

[image]

But when I decrease the `figsize` down to `(2,2)`, The plot shows (in my point of view) a weird behavior.

[image]

This, to me, looks like nothing is really preserved.

Distance between patchs, sizes of patches, and center coordinates of patches... everything is off.

How can I implement consistency for dimensions?

Also is there a better way that lets me spamming the same `PatchCollection` on different locations?

Comment: I think the number you are specifying in offset is a point, so if you specify it as a percentage of the total number of dots multiplied by the graph size and dpi, you will get the same result. `size=fig.get_size_inches()*fig.dpi;pc.set_offsets((i*size[0]/20,i*size[1]/20))`

Comment: "is there a better way...?": usually you would create just one collection with all patches and then set the offsets for this collection as an array/list